# How to select from different tables, order by date and limit with offset?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The db contains ***posts*** and ***cars*** tables.

Example data:

```
car.created_at: 2021-12-01
car.created_at: 2021-11-01
car.created_at: 2021-10-01
post.created_at: 2022-01-01
post.created_at: 2021-12-01
```

I need to select records from both **posts** and **cars** tables.

Also to order them in a descending order by **created_at** attribute.

And to limit them (thousands of records) with offset (pagination).

The final result should contain records from both tables and start from the newest record, in this case from `post.created_at: 2022-01-01`.

Comment: I'd expect every row in your result to contain both cars and posts data.

Comment: Do you simply want `ORDER BY GREATEST(p.created_at, c.created_at) DESC`?

Comment: Your JOIN condition is very strange...

Comment: Please provide some sample data and a sample result you would expect.

Comment: In addition to the requested  sample data and desired results post table definitions (ddl), all as text - **no images**.  Also update your question describing what you are trying the achieve, not (as provided) how you you wanted to do so.

Comment: @jarlh I expect both cars and posts. For example, db contains:
`car.created_at: 2021-12-01
car.created_at: 2021-11-01
car.created_at: 2021-10-01
post.created_at: 2022-01-01
post.created_at: 2021-12-01
`
The query should return `post.created_at: 2022-01-01` as the first row.
Example with `ORDER BY GREATEST` does not work.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear if this is what you want, but the following query would satisfy what you asked for:

```
  select created_at from cars
   union 
  select created_at from posts
order by created_at desc 
   limit 1 
  offset 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select COALESCE(car.created_at,post.created_at) cr_date
       from car full outer join post on false 
order by cr_date desc
offset 1 limit 3;
```

results

```
  cr_date
------------
 2021-12-01
 2021-12-01
 2021-11-01
```